# iOS Universal Links - NSUserActivity is nil

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am trying to use Universal Links. On clicking the link app launches on the iPad but in the delegate call continueUserActivity: userActivity variable is nil. Here is my code in AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willContinueUserActivityWithType:(NSString *)userActivityType
{
    if ([userActivityType isEqualToString: NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb])
    {

    }
    return true;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
    if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString: NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb]) {
        NSURL *url = userActivity.webpageURL;
        NSString *msg = [self getQueryComponentWithName:@"msg" fromURL:url];


    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using Debug build. It works when I use release mode. To build in release mode please use following steps:

1. Go to  Product menu
2. Select Scheme
3. Edit Scheme
4. In Build Configuration Select Release.